# Send Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus Message to BizTalk 2013 WCF-Custom

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, biztalk, azureservicebus, biztalk-2013

I need to send messages from a .NET Core app via the Azure Service Bus to BizTalk 2013. I have configured a WCF Custom receive port on BizTalk but on receiving a message get the following error:

> The adapter "WCF-Custom" raised an error message. Details "System.Xml.XmlException: The input source is not correctly formatted.

I've found examples using Windows.Azure.ServiceBus package and BrokeredMessage, but this is deprecated. I need to use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and the Message object.

I've tried many ways of serializing the XML but nothing seems to work.

In short I'm creating the message like this:

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<message>Hello world</message>"));
```

Is there a way to serialize the message correctly to be received by WCF in BizTalk 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

For anyone who needs to send messages via Azure Service Bus using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus Message to BizTalk 2013 WCF-Custom receive port.

```
var toAddress = "sb://yourbusname.servicebus.windows.net/yourqueuename";
var bodyXml = SerializeToString(yourSerializableObject); //

var soapXmlString = string.Format(@"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:a=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing""><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=""1"">*</a:Action><a:To s:mustUnderstand=""1"">{0}</a:To></s:Header><s:Body>{1}</s:Body></s:Envelope>",
                toAddress, bodyXml);

var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapXmlString);

var message = new Message { Body = content };
message.ContentType = "application/soap+msbin1";
```

This wraps the Xml in a proper SOAP format. Note the "to" embedded in the SOAP envelope is necessary (I found it didn't work using message.To).

For completeness, this is the serialization method (for clean xml):

```
public string SerializeToString<T>(T value)
{
    var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = false,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true
    };

    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamespaces);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```